# Set text in search bar of picker view for Address Book

Tags: iphone, ios, abaddressbook

I have followed Apple's [programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html) to extract a phone number from a user's Address Book. What I would like to do is to set a search value in the search bar of the picker view of the Address Book to narrow the list. Can it be done?

Note: I do not want to "import" the whole address book and do a search from there.

Comment: No, you can't open the address book from your app. Sounds like you want something like `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`

Comment: @danielbeard, it can be done. I can get a phone number from it. But now I want to reduce scrolling by the user to search for a contact. So I mainly want to insert a text into the search bar of the address book.

Comment: Some clarification is needed here. The programming guide linked is using `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`, so your question should be updated to reflect that you want to populate text in the picker view rather than the actual address book app.

Comment: @danielbeard, thanks for the clarification. So, can it be done?